# CSS - How to make if "Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE"?

Tags: css

I love the effect of using border and box-shadow inset but only "Chrome" does support the inset negative value `0px, 0px, -1px`.

However when I checked FF, Safari and IE (opera I don't have it but I bet it doesn't support it either)... There wasn't box-shadow at all.

When I inspect elements with firebug and try to type box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7) inset; it does appears but not with `-1px`. Then the value is invalid.

Does anybody know anything about this? If not how can I make "IF" the browser isn't chrome, then add positive value instead?

Comment: Put the fall back rule first then the rule that is only supported in chrome, all the browsers that doesn't support it will ignore it and use the previous rule

Comment: Yeh works for FF but not for safari :S strange. Even if -webkit is added safari doesnt recognize it.

Comment: Negative numbers aren't allowed in the third value in a box shadow, so `0px 0px -1px` is invalid. If it works in Chrome, it's a bug. Don't rely on it.

Comment: BoltClock +1 ... Good to know. But the effect with negative value is damn better then positive value :(

Comment: @NenaddvL Try it with the fourth parameter being negative. 0px 0px 2px -1px you might get the same effect you're digging now

Comment: @KyleMacey , Nothing seems to happen except that shadow disappear in every browser :(

Comment: you can also stack your shadows to achieve the desired effect (not sure what yours is though). You can have as many shadows as you want on a single element, both inset and normal, as long as you separate them by comma. Also i always put the inset first, but not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference... I'll go with the answer of the sachleen. Seems quite nice and easy. Thanks for all your answers people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way for this specific case, but I just want to share this.

[CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) is a pretty cool little JS file that allows you to specify CSS classes for specific browsers.

For example the following will only apply to elements with the `example` class if the browser is IE7.

```
.ie7 .example {
  background-color: orange
}
```

The page lists all the supported browsers and you can make a style that applies to everything but Chrome.

```
.ie, .ie7, .ie8, .opera, ... { style }
```

Comment: +1 ... well I hope that theres any other solution, if not Ill check this as an correct answer, as it is correct... Thanks for share sachleen.

Answer (score 2):

You could use user-agent detection to detect chrome browser:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

(taken from [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript))

and then:

```
// include this in the <head> of your doc
if (is_chrome) {
   <link href="chrome_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
} else {
    // do stuff for other browsers (or ignore)
}
```

It seems the word 'chrome' appears in most (if not all) chrome's user agent.
I found that [userAgentString.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) provides a list for previous user-agent strings of older versions as well.